# php передача длинного параметра Notice: Undefined property:

Tags: php

почему если  вызвать мою функцию с параметрами `printstr("fio->name");`
возникает ошибка

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass:

а если вместо функции прописать `echo($decoded->fio->name)` всё работает,
как это исправить? думаю что проблема в символе `->`

```
function printstr($ttl, $text) { 
    global $decoded; 
    if (!isset($decoded->$text) || empty($decoded->$text)) { return; } 

    echo('
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2 headings">'); 
    echo($ttl);
    echo('</div>
          <div class="col-md-5 content">'); 

    echo($decoded->$text); 
    //echo($decoded->fio->name);//работает
    echo('
      </div>
    </div>');
 } 

 $url = "***"; 
 $content = file_get_contents($url); 
 $decoded = json_decode($content); 

 printstr("num","id"); //работает
 printstr("fio","fio->name"); // не работает
```

Comment: да и не будет так работать в принципе.

Comment: вы пытаетесь в переменную вписать путь до вложенного объекта и обратиться к нему, такой фокус у вас не выйдет.

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayFormat($array, $prepend = '') {
    $results = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value)) {
            $results = array_merge($results, arrayFormat($value, $prepend . $key . '->'));
        } else {
            $results[$prepend . $key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

function printstr($ttl, $text) { 
    global $decoded; 
    if (!isset($decoded[$text]) || empty($decoded[$text])) { return; } 

    echo('
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2 headings">'); 
    echo($ttl);
    echo('</div>
          <div class="col-md-5 content">'); 

    echo($decoded[$text]); 
    //echo($decoded->fio->name);//работает
    echo('
      </div>
    </div>');
 } 

 $url = "***"; 
 $content = file_get_contents($url); 
 $decoded = arrayFormat(json_decode($content, true)); 



printstr("fio","fio->name");
```